# can we install multiple browsers in VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vnc-viewer

I have a requirement to test multiple browsers for my UI framework. 
I am guessing that i can use VNC viewer to login to the VM which is windows based and then install all the below browsers in it.

1. Chrome
2. Firefox
3. IE
4. Safari

is this possible? sorry if this is a trivial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. You will have no problem with Chrome and Firefox (which are cross-platform) and IE (which is for Windows). Safari will be tricky. From Wikipedia:

> Safari 5.1.7, released on May 9, 2012, is the last version available for Windows.

So, you will need to either run an older version of Safari, or have a second VM which is running Mac OS.